# Swagger: How to specify oneOf attribute for embedded element of the response?

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui

Assume, that we have the following controller method:

```
@ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(responseCode = "200")})
@GetMapping(value = "/animals", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public Flux<AnimalResponse> getAnimals() {

    return Flux.just(new AnimalResponse(new Dog("animal", "dog")));

}
```

where `AnimalResponse` looks like:

```
class AnimalResponse {
    private Animal animal;
}
```

and `Animal` class is abstract class:

```
abstract class Animal {

    private String animal;
}
```

that extended by two classes `Dog` and `Cat`:

```
class Cat extends Animal {
    private String cat; 
}


class Dog extends Animal {
    private String dog; 
}
```

With default Swagger configuration, it shows that the Controller response contains only one field `animal` that belongs to abstract class `Animal` and no information about other possible fields.
Seems to me, I need somehow specify `oneOf` Swagger property to `Animal` class, but I do not know how to do it properly, because usually `oneOf` attribute defined for `Response Object` not for the embedded element.
So,could you please advice?